# Main Activity BottomNavigationView overlap Fragment content

Tags: android, overlap, bottomnavigationview

I'm new on Android development and I'm facing some issue about BottomNavigationView and overlapping.

Here is what look like my app when everything it's fine :
[ViewPager2 without BottomNavigationView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGks6.png)

I have a GoogleMap fullscreen fragment and a ViewPager2 visible when user click on Google marker (to see details)

Now, when I add my BottomNavigationView, this is what it's look like : [BottomNavigationView overlapping my ViewPagers2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiF4v.png)

This is my `activity_main.xml` :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/common_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The `FragmentContainerView (@+id/common_fragment)` represent the fragment content displayed when user select an item in the BottomNavigationView. So, when user click on the center item, the follow `fragment_maps.xml` is display

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainMapsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true">

    <!-- My Google Map fragment -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/mapsFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The issue is, when I speficied `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` on my `@+id/viewPager`, parent is relative to the ConstraintLayout of my Fragment. I don't know if it's possible to add constraint inside my Fragment who refer to component in my Activity parent.

I have tried something like this `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"` instead of `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` but bottom_navigation is not visible from my fragment... [screenshot for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE43g.png)

I don't know how to tell to my ViewPager2 to position itself above my BottomNavigationView...

If you have any idea on my issue, or maybe I'm going in the wrong way, please tell me.

## Edit

I forgot to tell that I want to keep my BottomNavigationView overlapping my google map fragment. One of the futur evolution, is to set visible GONE all components (BottomNavigationView, FloatingButton) present on the map when user move the map. Given to the user a fullscreen google maps. And components will become VISIBLE after quick period of inactivity.

When adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"` to my `activity_main.xml`, my ViewPager2 is correctly display on top of my bottom_navitation. But when bottom_navigation GONE, the maps is stretched. And when bottom_navigation become VISIBLE, the maps is flattened.

Comment: In main_activity, the bottom of FragmentContainerView has to be constraint to the top of BottomNavigationView. Right now the FragmentContainerView goes to the end of the screen and the BottomNavigationView is on top.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I edited my request.

Answer (score 2):

In your FragmentContainer you have used `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` which causing problem.

You should use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"` in FragmentContainer. This will allow fragment above viewpager.

So your code becomes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/common_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```